# ElasticSearch NEST Upsert with set on insert

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, upsert

I have the following code to upsert documents to my index, which works well:

```
var dtos = new PlayerDto[]
{
    new PlayerDto 
    {
        Id = "1",
        AccountId = "1",
        Name = "test"
    }
};

var response = await _elastic.BulkAsync(b => b
    .Index(indexName)
    .UpdateMany(dtos, (bu, d) => bu.Doc(d).DocAsUpsert(true))
);
```

However, I don't want to override the `Name` field every time I upsert. Can I make it so the `Name` field is only set when the document is **inserted**, not **updated**? Or alternatively, set `Name` only if the existing `Name` is null?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just make field of the upserting document NULL. For example like this:

```
public class PlayerDto {
  public PlayerDto(PlayerDto model) {
    Id = model.Id,
    AccountId = model.AccountId,
    Name = null 
  }    
}

var response = await _elastic.BulkAsync(b => b
.Index(indexName)
.UpdateMany(dtos, (bu, d) => bu.Doc(new PlayerDto(d)).Upsert(d)));
```